# python прибавить к генерированному числу int

Tags: python, случайные-числа, int

```
import random
number = random.randint(1000000, 9999999)
b = 4444
c = b + number
print(c)
```

Comment: какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы 4444+randomчисло
чтобы результат был 444441526
4444215214
4444718223

Comment: То, что вы написали -  теперь по-русски называется "прибавить"??

Answer (score 3):

немного математики

```
import random
number = random.randint(1000000, 9999999)
b = 4444
c = b * 10000000 + number
print(c)
```

ну или что мешало сделать так:

```
import random
number = random.randint(44441000000, 44449999999)
print(number)
```

Comment: первое отлично подошло, спасибо, второе не совсем.
а почему там умножение, а не +?

Comment: чтобы получить число 25 надо 2 * 10 + 5, и почему второе не подошло?

Answer (score 3):

можно превратить в строку и потом обратно в число

```
c = int("4444" + str(number))
```

но лучше сразу генерировать числа в нужном диапозоне